# why some object doesn't show up color

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders, color

[image]

i add red color to cylinder but it doesn't show up color, only the plane with green have color.
what is the problem of my cylinder color?

Comment: It's cut off from the screenshot but there seem to be 2 material slots. The red material is on slot 2. What's on slot 1? Tried to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you've added the red material to material slot 2, so I guess there is a white material in slot 1. By default the complete object gets the first material. So the easiest way would be to delete the white material from the cylinder if that's the only one you want to show up.

Another way would be (if you want different colors on the cylinder) to go into *Edit Mode*, select those faces that should be red and hit *Apply* in the *Material Tab* to give them the material in the second slot.

[image: assign material]